# Extract Evenly Divisible using recursive function

Tags: javascript, recursion, division

I am trying following program but I have done without sorting so someone would please help me that how to sort return output?

Given a array of numbers, and a single number n, return an
extracted array of unique numbers that are
evenly divisible by n. Your extracted array should be
sorted in ascending numerical order.
Examples:
If you ran extractEvenlyDivisible([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3) you would get a return value of [3,6,9].
If you ran extractEvenlyDivisible([1,9,3,4,3,6,7,8,9], 3) you would get a return value of [3,6,9].

When giving by sort array then output coming sorted(3,6,9)::

```js
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
even_func(numbers,3);
function even_func(arr,n,i=0){
    if(arr[i] == undefined) return ;
    
    if(arr[i] % n == 0){
            console.log(arr[i]);
            var t  = arr.filter(x => {
              return x != arr[i];
            });
            arr = t; i=0;
    }
    even_func(arr, n,  i+1);   
}
```

But when giving unsorted array then output comes unsorted(9,3,6) so how to sort output like 3,6,9 without using global variables.

```js
var numbers = [1,9,3,4,3,6,7,8,9];
    even_func(numbers,3);
    function even_func(arr,n,i=0){
        if(arr[i] == undefined) return ;
        
        if(arr[i] % n == 0){
                console.log(arr[i]);
                var t  = arr.filter(x => {
                  return x != arr[i];
                });
                arr = t; i=0;
        }
        even_func(arr, n,  i+1);   
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

#### With JavaScript Array Functions

A simple approach is to use a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to filter out duplicates, then transform the `Set` back to an array so you can filter out the ones that can be divided by `n` without an remainder.
Then sort the values using [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).

```js
function evenNumber(array, divideBy){
    const set = new Set(array);
    const filtered = [...set].filter(number => number % divideBy === 0);
    return filtered.sort((a, b) => a - b);
}

console.log(evenNumber([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3));
console.log(evenNumber([1,9,3,4,3,6,7,8,9], 3));
```

#### Without using built-ins

As you said you don't want to use built-in functions in the comments here a solution without them following a different approach.

> It would of course also be possible to use the same approach as above using JS objects instead of a Set or by implementing an own version of Set and some sorting algorithm but I think that does not really make sense because you would just re-implement built-ins that are already implemented (and tested!) so I am following another approach here.

In this approach I keep an array `sorted` that is always sorted and will gradually be filled with values. First I loop over all values and check whether a value divides the given divider without leaving a remainder. If it does not, we can move on to the next element. If it does I need to check if we already have that in `sorted` array. Because it's sorted I can use binary search to do that and will be able to (not) find the value in `O(log n)`. I also remember the position computed by binary search where a value is found or if it's not in the array yet, the position where it would need to go.
Then if the value is already in the `sorted` array it can be ignored. If not, we have a new value to insert in the array. Thanks to the binary search we already know the position we need to put the new value.

```js
/**
 *
 * @param {Array<number>} array array to search
 * @param {number} value value to search for
 * @returns object containing boolean "found" and the position of the element; or if not found the position the value would need to be placed in in the array
 */
function binarySearch(array, value) {
  let left = 0;
  let right = array.length - 1;
  let lastLocation = 0;
  while (left <= right) {
    const middle = (right + left) >> 1;
    if (array[middle] === value)
      return {
        found: true,
        location: middle,
      };
    else if (array[middle] > value) {
      right = middle - 1;
      lastLocation = right;
    } else {
      left = middle + 1;
      lastLocation = left;
    }
  }
  return {
    found: false,
    location: Math.min(array.length, lastLocation + 1),
  };
}

/**
 *
 * @param {Array<number>} array array of numbers
 * @param {number} divideBy number which is used to divide each value by
 */
function evenNumber(array, divideBy) {
  // array that will always be sorted as we insert new values
  const sorted = new Array();
  // loop over all elements within the array
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const element = array[i];
    if (element % divideBy !== 0) continue;
    // search for the element in the array in O(log n)
    const result = binarySearch(sorted, element);
    // the value is already in the array => skip
    if (result.found) continue;
    // we have a new value to insert in the array
    // thanks to the binary search we already know the position we need to insert the element
    insertValue(sorted, element, result.location);
    
  }
  return sorted;
}

function insertValue(array, newElement, position) {
  if (position > array.length) position = array.length;
  else if (position < 0) position = 0;
  
  if (position < array.length) {
    // element is supposed to go to a spot where we already have a value (assuming a continious array)
    // increase array length by one and shift all values by 1 to the right so we get an empty spot at position
    array.length++;
    for (let i = array.length - 1; i > position; i--) {
      array[i] = array[i - 1];
    }
  }
  // set element at the position it is supposed to be in
  array[position] = newElement;
  return array;
}

console.log(evenNumber([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3));
console.log(evenNumber([1, 9, 3, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9], 3));
console.log(evenNumber([1, 9, 2, 12, 12, 16, 7, 8, 9, 5], 3));
```

`insertValue(array, newElement, position)` is the equivalent to  `sorted.splice(result.position, 0, element)`, so I would normally use this, because there's no point in just re-implementing built-in methods and it's also not a very safe way to operate.

You might wanna have a look at this [blog post](https://dmitripavlutin.com/the-magic-behind-array-length-property/) which give you a bit of background on some of the array operations I am doing.

Comment: You need to make that a numeric sort, or, for instance, `12` will come before `3`.  Perhaps `(ns, f) => [...new Set (ns)] .filter (n => n % f == 0) .sort ((a, b) => a - b)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response . I know about sort function but I don't want to use inbuilt functions. I have used a filter function because I had no idea how to do that hence i used filter function. Would you please sort this out without using an inbuilt functions like filter and sort?

Comment: I've added a version without built-in methods.

Comment: @Mushroomator Thank you for your effort but you forgot the concept of the program . We  have to do this only in recursive functions without using inbuilt functions, any loop and global variables.